# shell script in jenkins to fail a job

Tags: jenkins

I have a small shell script that the jenkins job calls in the 'Execute shell'. The shell script has some code to fail the build in the parameters passed in are incorrect

Here is the script.sh

```
    if [ $# != 2 ]; then
         echo "Your command should contain 2 arguments"
         exit 1
     fi
```

In the jenkins job i call this script has

```
   #!/bin/bash
   sh script.sh
```

When i call the shell script with no parmeters, i expect the build to fail.Instead it just prints the echo message and the job still shows success. How should I explicitly fail the build in this case?

Comment: I've used the same way to make job fail and it works. please make sure that the shell file you're invoking is the exactly right one, as you don't specify the absolute path in `sh script.sh`

Comment: if you're using a Jenkinsfile, post it and someone will call out the flaw. if you're not, Jenkinsfiles are awesome. :D